# selendroid--An error occurred while resigning the app 'selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk' through cmd

Tags: android

Got stuck after typing the following  line in cmd

```
D:\>java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.9.0-with-dependencies.jar -app selendroid-
test-app-0.9.0.apk
```

below is the error shown:

```
  Apr 23, 2014 11:15:48 AM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher main
  INFO: ################# Selendroid #################
  Apr 23, 2014 11:15:48 AM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher lauchServer
  INFO: Starting selendroid-server port 4444
  Apr 23, 2014 11:15:49 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
  INFO: executing command: D:\Softwares\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\build-
   tools\android-4.4\aapt.exe remove D:\\selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk META-INF/MAN
   IFEST.MF
  Apr 23, 2014 11:15:49 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
  INFO: executing command: D:\Softwares\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\build-
  tools\android-4.4\aapt.exe remove D:\\selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk META-INF/CER
   T.RSA
  Apr 23, 2014 11:15:49 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
  INFO: executing command: D:\Softwares\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\build-
  tools\android-4.4\aapt.exe remove D:\\selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk META-INF/CER
  T.SF
  Apr 23, 2014 11:15:49 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
  INFO: executing command: D:\Softwares\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\build-
   tools\android-4.4\aapt.exe remove D:\\selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk META-INF/AND
   ROIDD.SF
   Apr 23, 2014 11:15:49 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
  INFO: executing command: D:\Softwares\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\build-
  tools\android-4.4\aapt.exe remove D:\\selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk META-INF/AND
  ROIDD.RSA
  Apr 23, 2014 11:15:50 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
  INFO: executing command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\bin\keytool.exe -gen
  key -v -keystore C:\Documents and Settings\sysadmin\.android\debug.keystore -sto
 repass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -dname CN=Android Debug,O
 =Android,C=US -storetype JKS -sigalg MD5withRSA -keyalg RSA -validity 9999
 Apr 23, 2014 11:15:50 AM io.selendroid.Seln dendroidLauncher lauchServer


SEVERE: Error occurred while building servt   er: An eringror occurred while resigning
    the app 'selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk'.
    io.selendroid.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: An error occurred while res
     igning the app 'selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk'.
        at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplication
          sUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:114)
        at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.<init>(Selendro
```

Comment: I know this is old, but did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check that JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME env varibles are set properly and adb.exe is not running in background.

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon at the end when you set JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME env varibles